# Insert Page title into hidden form value with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a form on every page of my site via a template but I'd like to have the page title included into the emails sent via the forms so we know exactly which page the form was submitted from. Is there a simple way to do this with jquery?

Thanks for any tips/ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a hidden element with HTML:

```
<input id="pageTitle" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Include this javascript on your page (requires jQuery):

```
$("input#pageTitle").val(document.title);
```